# How to leave the ' ' in the result of a function in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
function concatString(val1, val2) {
  return val1 + " " + val2
  }
```

Examples:

```
('test', 'ok') => 'test ok';

('test', ' ') => 'test ';
```

Comment: result.trim() <-- shorter than 15 chars

Comment: which results are you expecting for  test-1 and test-2 ?

Answer (score 0):

Just embed the symbols into the literal return value.

```js
function concatString(val1, val2) {
  // Remove leading or trailing spaces from input
  val1 = val1.trim();
  val2 = val2.trim();
  return "'" + val1 + " " + val2 + "'";
}

console.log(concatString("test", "ok"));
console.log(concatString("test", " "));
```

Comment: there is only one space in the second test, not two....

Answer (score 0):

I would use a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

```js
function concatString(val1, val2) {
  return `'${val1} ${val2}'`
}

console.log(concatString("test", "ok"));
console.log(concatString("test", " "));
```

Comment: there is only one space in the second test, not two....

Comment: Can you comment on what is happening in the function so I can learn?

Comment: Sure! Although it doesn't look like it works exactly as you stated in your tests (as @MisterJojo mentioned). A format string works by letting you construct your string in a more user friendly way, imo. Here's a well explained tutorial showing you how it works :) https://www.tutorialstonight.com/javascript-string-format.php#:~:text=Formatting%20string%20in%20javascript%20is,a%20dollar%20sign%20(%24).&text=These%20variables%20are%20called%20placeholders,the%20values%20of%20the%20variables.

Comment: But you'll still need to `trim()` to avoid passed whitespace

Answer (score 0):

Check for condition add the val2 string. (If needed same can be extended to val1).

```js
function concatString(val1, val2) {
  let result = `${val1} `;
  return val2.trim() === "" ? result : result.concat(val2);
}

console.log(concatString("test", "ok"), '|');

console.log(concatString("test", " "), '|')
```